# Is it possible to play online using cross-platform?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

A friend and I have some games (e.g. NFS Rivals) in common. But he's playing using XBox One while I'm playing on PS4.

Is there a way to play those games together (online) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sony allows to have people in other platforms to interact with their players but MS don't.

One of the recent cases in last year that explained that to the user was Square Enix, regarding questions of why not having Final Fantasy XIV on Xbox.

Their answer was that since Microsoft has an strict policy concerning online servers, the xbox users would had to have their own private server, with no possibility of people transferring from/to and therefore SE gave up on the idea of porting to Xbox.

Check the [IGN interview with SE's Naoki Yoshida for more info](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/07/09/why-final-fantasy-xiv-isnt-coming-to-xbox-360-or-xbox-one) on this example:

> "The policy has not changed on Microsoft's side," he revealed. "The main reason from our side is that I don't want the community to be divided; to be split into two or more. For example, one player might be on the PC version, another might be on the PS4 version, and I'm playing the Xbox version - but we're not able to join the same game servers. That is just... I just don't like the idea. I disagree with it."

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry.

Due that Microsoft and Sony uses differents servers for online games. The only cross plataform that I know is with Steam and the Windows, Linux and Mac users.